# AngularJS UI.router redirects to horrible url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `angular-ui-router 1.0.3` and I'm trying to implement this url `http://localhost:8888/details/2020?pending=true` but when I type that url in the browser and hit `enter` when the page loads, automatically change the url to this `http://localhost:8888/app/details/%7BParam:orderid%20%7BParamType:path%7D%20squash:%20'false'%20optional:%20false%7D?pending=%7BParam:pending%20%5Bobject%20Object%5D%20squash:%20%27false%27%20optional:%20true%7D`

This is my app.config() code

```
$stateProvider.state('details',{
   url:'/details/:orderid?pending',
   name:'details',
   templateUrl:'/views/details.html',
   resolve:{
            load:function($q, $rootScope){
                var dfrd = $q.defer();
                require(['/js/details.js'],function(){
                    dfrd.resolve();
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                })
                return dfrd.promise;
            }
        }
})
```

If I use `$state.go({details:2020,pending:true})` from other views works perfect. The problem appears when I hit Enter in the URL

Also I'm getting this error in the console:

> angular-ui-router.min.js:sourcemap:13 Transition Rejection($id: 0
>   type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different
>   transition, detail: Transition#1( ''{} ->
>   'details'{"orderid":"{Param:orderid {ParamType:path} squash: 'false'
>   optional: false}"} ))

Comment: your url stops with orderid. question mark and pending is not included.

Comment: remove question mark and pending from the url in config file.

Comment: same result with `url:'/details/:orderid'`. when realod  `http://localhost:8888/details/2020` becomes 
 `http://localhost:8888/details/%7BParam:orderid%20%7BParamType:path%7D%20squash:%20'false'%20optional:%20false%7D`

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
In my app.run() I had:

```
$transitions.onBefore({},function(event) {
        var target = event._targetState._definition;
        $rootScope.toState = target.name
        $rootScope.toParams = target.params
        if(target.name == 'signin') return true;
        return auth.signin();
});
```

But all the problems were for use `$rootScope`  inside the `onBefore` event. So the final code for my implementation is: **(note the absence of `$rootScope`)**:

```
$transitions.onBefore({},function(event) {
        var target = event._targetState._definition;
        if(target.name == 'signin') return true;
        return auth.signin({toState:target.name,toParams:target.params});
});
```

and this piece of code without changes:

```
$stateProvider.state('details',{
   url:'/details/:orderid?pending',
   name:'details',
   templateUrl:'/views/details.html',
   resolve:{
            load:function($q, $rootScope){
                var dfrd = $q.defer();
                require(['/js/details.js'],function(){
                    dfrd.resolve();
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                })
                return dfrd.promise;
            }
        }
})
```